# How to group by on multiple levels on a dataframe on R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that contains the aggregation of transactions over gender column and age groups column, i want to make the gender categories as two columns (female, male), and the row labels are the age groups.

how it is:

[image: how it is:]

i made it through this code:

```
df_1 <- OrPatientTotals %>%
          filter(DomainID==1) %>%
          group_by(DisplayEn, GenderEn) %>%
          summarise(SumTransactions = sum(TotalTransactions))
```

how i want it to be

[image: how i want it to be]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow btw! You may want to look into the pivot_wider() function

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_wider()` from the [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) package:

```
library(tidyverse)

DisplayEn <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
GenderEn <- c('Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male')
SumT <- c(3770, 8149, 11201, 23232, 18948, 32615)

data <- tibble(DisplayEn = DisplayEn,
               GenderEn = GenderEn,
               SumT = SumT)

data |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = GenderEn, values_from = SumT) |>
  mutate(Sum = Female + Male)
```